# Woocomarce Reorder the position of title and stars in shop page

Tags: woocommerce, customization

I want to reorder the product title on the shop page to be in this order :

Title
Subtitle
Price
Stars rating
Add to cart

[The goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTgYn.png)

I need the rating stars after the price

Comment: What have you tried so far and what issue do you see with your attempts?

Comment: I tried to apply this hook 

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_ loop_price
', 'woocommerce_template_loop_rating', 5 );

Comment: `woocommerce_after_shop_ loop_price` is not a valid action hook. Hook names are not imaginary they are defined in files. Please read this [content-product.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/trunk/plugins/woocommerce/templates/content-product.php) file and add/remove functions on the correct hook with correct priority.

Comment: I tried to do something like this, but with the rating :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65977030/move-woocommerce-products-prices-above-the-products-titles-in-shop-page

woocommerce_template_loop_rating
woocommerce_template_loop_price

with the main element